# Java xml unmarshalling list nested object issue

Tags: java, xml

I have a xml with content below:

```
<ParentClass>
    <StringA>A</StringA>
    <StringB>B</StringB>
    <Items>
        <Item ts="2016-03-25T20:00:00+02:00">1.17</Item>
        <Item ts="2016-03-25T21:00:00+02:00">1.15</Item>
    </Items> 
</ParentClass>
```

I would like to read it but I got stuck on proper mapping. Classes are as below:

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Data
public class ParentClass {
    @XmlElement(name = "StringA", required = true)
    private String a;
    @XmlElement(name = "StringB", required = true)
    private String b;
    @XmlElement(name = "Items", required = true)
    private List<Item> consumptionList;

}

@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Data
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Item {
    @XmlAttribute(name = "ts", required = true)
    @XmlJavaTypeAdapter(value = LocalDateTimeAdapter.class)
    private LocalDateTime timestamp;
    private double value; //this corrensponds to 1.17 and 1.15 in xml
}
```

In the actual file there are 100+ items yet when I read it the list is populated with only one instance of Item class and it has both fields null.

I guess the mapping in the Item class is all wrong but tried all and nothing seems to work.

How should I properly map it to achieve the goal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add `@XmlValue` to field `value`, otherwise it defaults to `@XmlElement`.

Also, you need to change the annotations on `consumptionList` to

```
@XmlElementWrapper(name = "Items")
@XmlElement(name = "Item", required = true)
```

Also be aware that the `ts` values are `OffsetDateTime` (or `ZonedDateTime`) values, not `LocalDateTime`, unless your `LocalDateTimeAdapter` applies a time zone, e.g. the JVM default time zone.

I've found that the best way to help apply `@Xml...` annotations correctly, is to create objects and marshal them to XML to see what you get. Your current code will create this XML:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<ParentClass>
    <StringA>A</StringA>
    <StringB>B</StringB>
    <Items ts="2016-03-25T20:00:00+02:00">
        <value>1.17</value>
    </Items>
    <Items ts="2016-03-25T21:00:00+02:00">
        <value>1.15</value>
    </Items>
</ParentClass>
```

If you apply the changes mentioned above, you get:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<ParentClass>
    <StringA>A</StringA>
    <StringB>B</StringB>
    <Items>
        <Item ts="2016-03-25T20:00:00+02:00">1.17</Item>
        <Item ts="2016-03-25T21:00:00+02:00">1.15</Item>
    </Items>
</ParentClass>
```

The above outputs were created by adding this code:

```java
class LocalDateTimeAdapter extends XmlAdapter<String, LocalDateTime> {
    @Override
    public String marshal(LocalDateTime time) throws Exception {
        return time.atZone(ZoneOffset.ofHours(2))
                   .format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("uuuu-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssxxx"));
    }
    @Override
    public LocalDateTime unmarshal(String text) throws Exception {
        return ZonedDateTime.parse(text).toLocalDateTime();
    }
}
```

```java
public static void main(String... args) throws Exception {
    ParentClass p = new ParentClass("A", "B", Arrays.asList(
            new Item(LocalDateTime.parse("2016-03-25T20:00:00"), 1.17),
            new Item(LocalDateTime.parse("2016-03-25T21:00:00"), 1.15)));

    JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(ParentClass.class);
    Marshaller marshaller = jaxbContext.createMarshaller();
    marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, Boolean.TRUE);
    marshaller.marshal(p, System.out);
}
```